What is the purpose of react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values if I'm not using memo()
When using Context
<SomeContext.Provider value={{ something: 123 }}>
  ...
</SomeContext.Provider>

I get the following error from ESLint:

The object passed as the value prop to the Context provider (at line
129) changes every render. To fix this consider wrapping it in a
useMemo hook.

This rule seems slightly aggressive to me as my understanding was that Context works in the same way as other re-renders (if the component that is recalculating the value prop is being re-rendered anyways, it's going to re-render the entire subtree regardless, unless memo() is used somewhere).
Is my understanding correct that this really doesn't matter unless I have a Consumer component somewhere down the tree that is memo()d? And if that's the case, why doesn't ESLint just tell us to memo() literally every object that's reconstructed on renders to be consistent?

{ something: 123 } is a new object reference each time the provider renders. It's informing you to provide a stable reference to downstream consumers. I wouldn't consider this aggressive at all. If you feel it's too aggressive and don't care, then update the linting rule to a warning instead of an error.

Also, forcing all downstream consumers to memoize the value if it needs to be is a bit wasteful when you could just do it once in the provider and provide a stable reference and be done with it.
